# rewrite_mod ignoring variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I currently have this `RewriteRule` below, which give me something from:

www.example.com/post.php?bID=3&title=blog-title (original)

TO:

www.example.com/blog/3/blog-title (modified)

```
#Blog Rewrite
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /post.php\?bID=(\d+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /post.php?bID=$1&title=$2 [NE,L]
```

How can I edit my rules in order to keep the same structure of the original URL, but ignore/hide the 'bID' ("/3") variable for the modified url, so I'd have a final modified url only as www.example.com/blog/blog-title?

Also, while ignoring/hiding the 'bID' from the modified URL, can I still parse/get the parameter value?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to work with **GET** variables, [just use](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString) `%{QUERY_STRING}`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} bID=(\d+)&title=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /blog/%1/%2? [R,L,NE]
```